# Codeigniter using autoloaded model

Tags: php, codeigniter, models

I add a model in autoload file like this:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('themodel');
```

And i want to know how to use it in the controller because when i write $this it get the current controller functions

Thanks,

Comment: basics of framework usage, covered thruly in manual. would have given -1 if i had enough rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$this->themodel->some_function()`

And I suggest you do your homework on [models in CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html).